# Create Multi line chart from datatable in WindowsForm C#

Tags: c#, datatable, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to draw a multiline chart from a datatable, my datatable looks like that

[image]

and the chart should like that:

[image]

I tried to do it using this code but it didn't work:.

```
DataTable dt = GetParametertable(alternative, criterionRating);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        line_chart.Series.Add("series1");
        line_chart.Series["series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        line_chart.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Don't bind the whole chart; instead bind the Points of one Series! Also: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for an overview! Also: You should not try to bind the fields in a row but one column in  each row! Your table can only support 3 ros and even those won't have an x-value.. - Finally your numbers don't look anything like your image..?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add multiple series and specify the YValueMembers field for each series.

```
line_chart.Series.Add("series1");
line_chart.Series["series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
line_chart.Series["series1"].YValueMembers = "Alt1";
line_chart.Series.Add("series2");
line_chart.Series["series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
line_chart.Series["series2"].YValueMembers= "Alt2";
line_chart.Series.Add("series3");
line_chart.Series["series3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
line_chart.Series["series3"].YValueMembers = "Alt3";
line_chart.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment for now so I'm gonna post this as an answer.

Have you tried calling DataBind() and Update() after assigning DataSource?